# HOW TO VLOOKUP DATA WITH CONDITION

Tags: excel, vlookup

i want to change data layout by filtering the left table from redundancies i tried typing the below formula =IF(VLOOKUP(K8,$A$8:$E$82,5,FALSE)=$N$7,VLOOKUP(K8,$A$8:$E$82,4,FALSE),"na") it just works with the date 3/1/2021 but not for the rest of the columns for the rest of dates

anyone can help me with this problem?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pPh4X3wxHjfXLEsaSVbG3qDc_JB_j9u2iRu8wsA9kQY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please don't ask a duplicate while your previous question remains unanswered.

Comment: And don’t shout.